# Restore baseband/IMEI of Motorola Moto E5 Plus (Hannah) (XT1924-7)

Tags: restore, motorola, imei, baseband

I have an issue with the baseband/IMEI of my Motorola Moto E5 Plus.

Could this have been caused by flashing a firmware version with RSU (Russian?) found in a repository on XDA with the stock("") firmware and restoration guide and made the mistake of not checking the file thoroughly and believe I flashed the right carrier and version but the wrong region?  I've been digging all over XDA and elsewhere and tried using Lenovo device repair assistant to no avail.

Also, would flashing the HLOS omg be a possible fix? From what I've been able to discover on my own, it seems that is where the instructions for the radio come from in firmware?

I know I'm an amateur but any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever solve your issues?
My backups were faulty (my fault).
I tried the same version of OTA I was on from: https://mirrors.lolinet.com/firmware/moto/hannah/official/Metropcs/ and boot failed. So I downloaded the newest OTA from the same link, that flashes fine. IMEI/bands/all that work fine.

I can not verify authenticity though.

What I did:

1. Download the newest OTA from lolinet
2. Uncompress `ota.zip` to a new folder
3. Open the new folder, open `flashfile.xml` on part of the screen (I just let IE open it, Notepad++ would be fine also)
4. Open `cmd` from Start/search on another part of the desktop screen (command prompt)
5. `cd desktop`, `cd newOTAfolder`
6. Boot phone into Download mode (power off, hold power/volume down)
7. Following the flashfile

   ```
   fastboot oem fb_mode_set
   fastboot flash partition gpt.bin
   fastboot flash bootloader bootloader.img
   fastboot flash modem NON-HLOS.bin
   fastboot flash fsg fsg.mbn
   fastboot erase modemst1
   fastboot erase modemst2
   fastboot flash dsp adspso.bin
   fastboot flash logo logo.bin
   fastboot flash boot boot.img
   fastboot flash recovery recovery.img
   fastboot flash system system.img_sparsechunk.0
   fastboot flash system system.img_sparsechunk.1
   fastboot flash system system.img_sparsechunk.2
   fastboot flash system system.img_sparsechunk.3
   fastboot flash system system.img_sparsechunk.4
   fastboot flash vendor vendor.img
   fastboot flash oem oem.img
   fastboot erase cache
   fastboot erase userdata
   fastboot erase DDR
   fastboot oem fb_mode_clear
   fastboot reboot
   ```

This gets you Completely wiped/Stock.
Please follow the `flashfile.xml`, just use my iteration as a guide to reading it.

I use an adb/fastboot that is system-wide. If you just download the self-contained adb/fastboot, you need to uncompress the `OTA.zip` from lolinet into the adb/fastboot folder.

For what it is worth, on the METRO/Moto E5 Plus, the best custom ROM I have found is AOSPe/AEX. I am currently going back to STOCK and modding that though as all over ROMs have been faulty in ways that make for not using as a daily driver.